# "Easing-out" an infinite CSS rotation animation when another div is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, rotation

I'm trying to use jquery to bring a constantly rotating div (using CSS animation) to a slow, smooth stop when another div is clicked.

I've been attempting to change the "animation-timing-function" property from "linear" to "ease-out", but it just stops abruptly, as opposed to the slow stop I want.

HTML

```
<div id=click>Click me</div>
<div id=spinner></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
$("#click").click(

function () {
    document.getElementById("spinner").style['-moz-animation-iteration-count'] = '1';
    document.getElementById("spinner").style['-moz-animation-timing-function'] = 'ease-out';
    document.getElementById("spinner").style['-webkit-animation-iteration-count'] = '1';
    document.getElementById("spinner").style['-webkit-animation-timing-function'] = 'ease-out';
    document.getElementById("spinner").style['animation-iteration-count'] = '1';
    document.getElementById("spinner").style['animation-timing-function'] = 'ease-out';

});
});
```

CSS

```
#spinner {
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin:20px;
background-color:red;

animation:spin-constant 5s;
-webkit-animation-name: spin-constant;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1200ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: spin-constant;
-moz-animation-duration: 1200ms;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: spin-constant;
animation-duration: 1200ms;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin-constant {
from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-constant {
from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
@keyframes spin-constant {
from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}
to {
    transform:rotate(36 0deg);
}
}
```

Here is the fiddle of the basic concept.
http://jsfiddle.net/jN5vw/1/

Comment: Except for the way you call the #click element this isn't jQuery. Not sure what your question is?

Comment: It is quite messy, I am quite new to the world of web development. I guess I am just asking how to accomplish my goal using some combination of CSS and JS/Jquery

Comment: This is going to be tough since you're animating it with purely CSS. If this was done with a JavaScript loop you could decrement the rotation value slowly, but with CSS I'm not sure.  I know there is a jQuery method to `addClass` and `removeClass` with a slow delay to transition between the old and new classes but it'll  take some doing to figure out which value results in a smooth stop. I suspect you'll want to change the animation-duration to higher and higher ms values over at least a couple seconds and as you get near the end of the count up change your iteration-count to 1 from infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

[See Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jN5vw/11/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('#click').click(function () {

    $("#spinner").removeClass('spinner');
    $("#spinner").addClass('anim');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.anim{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:red;
    animation:spin 5s ;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
}
```

I think this is what you are asking.

Comment: Still looks pretty "unsmooth" to me.

Comment: yes, this is not smooth, since user may click at random rotation state, but "ease" will start from predefined rotation state :(